# JAXB & UTF-8 Unmarshal exception "Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence"

Tags: java, xml, unicode, jaxb

I've read a few SO answers that say that JAXB has a bug that it blames on XML's nature which cause it to not work with UTF-8.  My question is, so what is the workaround?  I may get unicode character entered by my users copying and pasting into a data field that I need to preserve, marshal, unmarshal, and re-display elsewhere.

(update)
More Context:

```
Candidate c = new Candidate();
c.addSubstitution("3 4ths", "\u00BE");
c.addSubstitution("n with tilde", "\u00F1");
    c.addSubstitution("schwa", "\u018F");
    c.addSubstitution("Sigma", "\u03A3");
    c.addSubstitution("Cyrillic Th", "\u040B");     
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Candidate.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(c, os);
    String xml = os.toString();
    System.out.println(xml);    
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Candidate.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxb = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    Candidate newCandidate = (Candidate) jaxb.unmarshal(is);
    for(Substitution s:c.getSubstitutions()) {
        System.out.println(s.getSubstitutionName() + "='" + s.getSubstitutionValue() + "'");
    }
```

Here's a little test bit I threw together.  The exact characters I get are not entirely under my control.  users may paste a N with tilde into the field or whatever.

Comment: You should give more context - what exactly are you doing? Do you have a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? Which characters are causing problems?

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated with more context.  The above example will exception.

Comment: The Candidate object is a bean of ours with some fairly normal JAXB annotations.  It works fine until unicode characters.

Comment: _"XML's nature which cause it to not work with UTF-8"_ -- XML works fine with UTF-8 as long as it's all UTF-8.  Clearly, at some point in your data flow, a non-UTF-8 byte sequence is being inserted into your data. Probably a user pastes a Windows-1252 character into an input field and that data is not being encoded to UTF-8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the problem in your test code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
```

You're using the platform default encoding to convert the string to a byte array. **Don't do that.** You've specified that you're going to use UTF-8, so you must do so when you create the byte array:

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Likewise don't use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()`, which again uses the platform default encoding. Indeed, you don't need to convert the output to a string at all:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
marshaller.marshal(c, os);
byte[] xml = os.toByteArray();
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Candidate.class);
Unmarshaller jaxb = jc.createUnmarshaller();
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml);
```

This should have no problems with the characters you're using - it will still have problems which can't be represented in XML 1.0 (characters below U+0020 other than `\r`, `\n` and `\t`) but that's all.